# Global Profile for SE?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

On S[OFU] and on *stackexchange i would like my profile to be the same for each and everyone of them. Can we have a global profile update? It sure beats copy/pasting to every SE site i belong to (i think the count is 8 + SOFU and meta's)

Comment: I've been using "SOFUE", which--I suppose--may be pronounced "so few"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the site that has the profile you want everywhere, go to the "accounts" tab on your user page, and click "copy profile to related accounts."

Comment: Oh thanks! I never notice or used that account tab. I thought it would be in the edit page (as save to all). This is really useful thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need, we **auto-copy the profile with the highest reputation** to each new site you join, at the time of account creation.

The only time that would get weird is if you had a lot of reputation on a site you didn't want the profile to copy from.

Comment: re: weird - yeah, it'll suck when cutepuppiesandkittens.stackexchange.com goes into beta, then any new profiles I might make would say, "I love my Snuffles and Woofums and hope to share exciting pictures of their adventures with you daily!" as I eclipse 50k on that site.

Comment: @polly yes this happened to Sam Saffron -- his waffles account on meta has the most rep so it gets copied around, instead of his SO profile

Comment: My StackExchange profile gives the following message: "Sync with oldest profile (Meta Stack Overflow). Last sync 17h ago.", but my most active site is StackOverflow (also, this is where I would like my profile to come from).  StackOverflow and Meta both read 'Joined  September 22'.  Even after doing a copy from my StackOverflow, my StackExchange profile is empty.