# Why isn't there an option for the "global" profile not to copy one of your profiles?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, network-profile

I'm surprised this isn't already a question, but I couldn't find it.

When you create a "global" profile for SE sites, like the one you're supposed to link to for your personal site, e.g.

```
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/######.png">
```

you can only copy one of your other profiles.  Well, that isn't really helpful, since one might get pretty specific about why you are on that particular site (Stack Overflow, Academia, Sci-fi, Linguistics) and none might be very helpful.

Picture:

[image]

I guess that in some sense this is a feature request, but for now let's just say it's a question for why this decision was made.  Note: this is *not* a dup of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65998/global-profile-for-se).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because stackexchange.com itself is a read-only site. You cannot modify any part of your account from that site directly, and we're not going to add any UI options to that site to let you have a custom profile text (in fact, we prefer to *remove* UI from that site whenever possible).

Your only option that will ever be there is to have it be the same as another site on the network by copying it from that specific site.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  Probably better to keep it blank, then.  Thanks!